# How to enable application insights on All APIs level in azure api management by using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I'm managing my azure API management (APIs and policies) by using terraform.
Most of the things are working fine and the documentation on https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs is great.
But now I need to activate application insights diagnostic logs with verbosity `error` on `All-APIs` level. Unfortunately I don't understand how to do that by checking the documentation. Can someone help me how to do that?

This is how it looks like when I set it through the UI.

[image: this is what I want to achieve with terraform]

I hope someone can help

Comment: Is this the screenshot from your azure portal you added?

Comment: Do you have application insight instance created in your resource group?

Comment: yes this screenshot is from my azure portal. if I enable the diagnostics logs for one specific API though terraform everything works fine, but I don't understand how I can set it on "All APIs" level. `azurerm_api_management_api_diagnostic` wants  an `api_name` but I don't have an `azurerm_api_management_api` object for "All APIs". https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_diagnostic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[azurerm_api_management_diagnostic](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_diagnostic) should be what you are looking for

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "example-appinsights"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"
  sku_name            = "Developer_1"
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_logger" "example" {
  name                = "example-apimlogger"
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  application_insights {
    instrumentation_key = azurerm_application_insights.example.instrumentation_key
  }
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_diagnostic" "example" {
  identifier               = "applicationinsights"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name      = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  api_management_logger_id = azurerm_api_management_logger.example.id

  sampling_percentage       = 5.0
  always_log_errors         = true
  log_client_ip             = true
  verbosity                 = "Verbose"
  http_correlation_protocol = "W3C"

  frontend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "accept",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  frontend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "content-length",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  backend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "accept",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  backend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "content-length",
      "origin",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that hint, I'll try it out but I think it is something else as it doesn't allow me to set the verbosity of the diagnostic logs which results in huge amount of log data (and unfortunately high costs :/). In the Azure portal I can activate the diagnostic logs on api management level too, but as I said, thats not what I'm searching for.

Comment: @sschoebinger check again :) in the latest provider version 2.46.0 there was an update to azurerm_api_management_diagnostic which contains more fields now

Comment: Oh thanks I checked to documentation and it look promising. I’ll give it a try 